# How to return an Observable when other observable is done

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am extending a class which already has a method which returns `Observable`,
as below, I want to return the base observable after the result of first observable is returned (after getting `token` from another service),

so I develop codes like below, but typescript compiler doesn't accept because I am not returning `Observeable<Response>`, it will be returned in `subscribe` method

```
 post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.tokenService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
      //injecting token into options
      return super.post(url, body, options);
    });

}
```

Also I tried creating a new Observable like below, but still no chance

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
     return new Observable<Response>(observer => {
        this.tokenService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
          //injecting token into options
          //observer.complete??? super.post(url, body, options);
        });

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to convert one observable into another observable:

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.tokenService.getToken().flatMap(token => {
      //injecting token into options
      return super.post(url, body, options);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still I get compile error because nothing is returned
`A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

Comment: sorry I left out that you `return` the flatMapped observable.  I've fixed the example.